# Сбой при получении производства объектов класса COM

Tags: .net, com

Есть приложение на C#  - cbmon.exe (целевая платформа x86, NetFramework 3.5).
Есть COM компонент на C++ - PI2Disp.dll (целевая платформа x86, NetFramework 3.5).
При загрузке Cbmon.exe загружается PI2Disp.dll, чтобы установить соединение с оборудованием и получать от него сообщения. Под WIN32 все работает замечательно. (Win XP, Win Vista, Win 7). Проблема возникает на Win 8.1 64x. Устанавливаю программу. Регистрирую PI2Disp.dll командой:

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 PI2Disp.dll
```

из командной строки с правами администратора. Регистрация прошла успешно.
Запускаю службы компонентов – Настройка DCOM, нахожу в списке свой компонент PI2Disp, открываю Свойства, Безопасность и даю права по максимуму в списке всем пользователям на запуск, на доступ, на изменение. Запускаю Cbmon.exe с правами администратора. Получаю ошибку:

> Адресат вызова создал исключение.: Сбой при получении производства объектов
> класса COM для компонента с CLSID {E062D4F8-6083-402F-ABD6-A4EB0F0FFD01} в
> результате следующей ошибки: 80070005.

С CLSID {E062D4F8-6083-402F-ABD6-A4EB0F0FFD01} в реестре зарегистрирован класс из COM компонента PI2Disp.dll.
В разъяснении к ошибке написано:

> ASP.NET не имеет права обращаться к запрошенному ресурсу. Рекомендуется
> предоставить идентификатору запроса ASP.NET права доступа к этому ресурсу.
> ASP.NET имеет базовый идентификатор процесса (обычно {MACHINE}\ASPNET для IIS > 5 или Network Service на IIS 6), который используется, если приложение не
> олицетворяется. Если приложение олицетворяется через задание , идентификатором будет служить идентификатор анонимного
> пользователя (обычно IUSR_MACHINENAME) или идентификатор пользователя запроса > с проверенной подлинностью.
>
> Для предоставления ASP.NET прав на запись в файл, щелкните на файле правой
> кнопкой мыши в окне "Проводник", выберите "Свойства", затем вкладку
> "Безопасность". Выберите "Добавить" для добавления соответствующего
> пользователя или группы. Выделите учетную запись ASP.NET и установите флажки
> для требуемых прав доступа.

Если я правильно понимаю, должна присутствовать учетная запись MACHINE или ASPNET или IUSR_MACHINENAME, которой надо дать права на этот объект.  Но ничего подобного в списке пользователей на вкладке безопасность для PI2Disp у меня нет. На машине установлен NET Framework 4.0. Объясните, пожалуйста, что еще нужно сделать или что я сделала не так. Большое спасибо.

Comment: PI2Disp.dll - это COM. и он используется в cbmon.exe (windows приложение), а также в asp.net приложении?

Comment: PI2Disp.dll  в данном случае используется только в cbmon.exe.

Comment: Уточнение: есть еще обертка PI2DispNet.dll на PI2Disp.dll, созданная с помощью программы импорта библиотек типов (Tlbimp.exe). Но она не является COM объектом и не регистрируется и на нее тоже всем пользователям даны все права.

Comment: понятно. если есть asp.net приложение, которое хостится в IIS, то для учетной записи, с которой работает IIS, надо настроить права доступа.

Comment: нет приложения asp.net, которое бы хостилось в IIS. PI2DispNet.dll - это обертка на СОМ, библиотека типов, понятных среде CLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, в Component Services в папке «COM+ Applications» лежал объект PI2Disp_Connect. Не могу сейчас  объяснить зачем он там создавался. СОМ не предназначался для работы по сети. После его удаления все заработало.